Why did my 50µm gold wire vanish when I tried to tin it?
I was trying to tin 50µm gold wire to solder it to something bigger, but touching the gold wire to a bit of molten solder on the tip of an iron caused a couple of mm of wire to disappear.  The solder I'm using is 100% tin, flux cored, and the iron is probably at about 350°C (it's a fixed temperature Weller).  The wire didn't snap; it's far too flexible for that and nothing landed on the bench.  I did eventually manage to get a join by touching the gold wire to hook-up wire wet with molten solder, just before that solidified - but it may not be a very good join.
So where did the gold go? Gold plating on PCBs doesn't seem to dissolve off in tin, so could that be happening to wire?  It certainly can't be melting

For background: I'm prototyping an optical setup using a surface mount LED on a stick (for test purposes,  an 0603 - 0.8×1.6mm - on a trimmed cocktail stick, will be a custom plastic part and an 0402). For the last few mm of wire to be as unobtrusive as possible, I'm using 0.05mm 99.9% gold wire normally used for wire bonding (which we have in the lab anyway).  I wanted to solder this onto some 30AWG hookup wire that's robust enough to join to the outside world

30AWG copper should survive soldering OK, but 40AWG copper can suffer the same disappearing act as your gold wire scenario.

Gold dissolves in tin, rather quickly. A wire as narrow as 50 μm would dissolve almost instantaneously.
Gold plating on PCBs does in fact dissolve into the solder; ENIG plating is only meant to prevent oxidation until the board is soldered, after which point the gold pretty much completely dissolves into the solder. If you were to somehow remove all the solder (not a trivial task), you'd be left with just exposed nickel.
Wire this thin is not meant to be soldered, and likely can't be soldered. (edit: according to @jackb in the comments, it can indeed be soldered with care, using low temperature and continuously feeding wire into the joint. That'll teach me to make assumptions about the skill of engineering technicians!) What you have is most likely intended to be wirebonded, a process that requires specialized machinery that simultaneously applies heat, pressure, and ultrasonic energy to form a (rather fragile, but stronger than the tiny wire itself) bond between the wire and a metal pad on top of an IC. It may also be possible to make a connection to it by crimping, but it would be very easy to break the wire in the process.

Yes, it is wirebonder wire - we have a wirebonder.  We also use this wire with conductive epoxy, which looks like what I'll be doing next (and is how I plan to make the connections to the LED).  I've done dead bug style SMD work before, but not for over 20 years.  We're a research group that makes semiconductor lasers, and I'm designing a new characterisation system, using the stuff we have to mock up my prototype

@ChrisH Yeah, conductive epoxy should work too. You may be able to use very fine nickel wire--nickel dissolves into solder much slower than copper or gold, while still being wettable. That's part of why it's used as a barrier layer in gold platings, in fact. (The larger part being that it stops the gold from dissolving into the copper.) You may also try using other solders, if you really want to solder this; I know leaded solder dissolves copper slower than standard lead-free SAC305, but I'm not sure how they compare when it comes to gold. SN100C is in a similar position.

Thanks.  Soldering is just a means to an end here, and what I thought would be the easy end compared to the connection to the LED.  Simultaneously I've discovered some even smaller LEDs (0603 metric, i.e. 0.65×0.35mm) but the contact geometry is less helpful so I'm reviewing my whole design

And a little reading suggests leaded should be better here because gold isn't soluble in lead.  We have some 60/40 so I might try that

@ChrisH 60/40 is still 60% tin, and gold is very soluble in tin, so it may not work. Worth a try, though. Maybe give In52Sn48 a try too; I have no idea what the solubility of gold is like in indium, but it also has a melting point of something like 130 celsius, so the temperature can be lower.

I'd go for the conductive epoxy we have over ordering new stuff, at least at this stage. For a different project I'm looking at higher temperature solders, which are lead-based anyway, with little or no tin, so maybe they'd serve double duty

Although I could get my hands on a little pure indium from another lab, and gold apparently doesn't dissolve in In.  I'd need to check our filters could handle In fumes because breathing them isn't good.

It is possible to solder gold all the way down to 12 um in 60/40, I did this routinely during my PhD. It's tricky though. You have to keep the temperature of the solder as low as possible without solidifying, and the time in contact with the gold as short as possible. I used to melt the solder, then slowly but continuously push the gold into it until the solder solidifies and the gold wire buckles. Some of the gold dissolves but the piece that was pushed in a moment before solidification stays intact.  The resulting joint is not very strong, but was stronger than 12um wire.

@JackB That method I would guess relies on saturating the solder with gold; once there's too much gold in solution, it won't dissolve any more. Actually a pretty good idea that I didn't think of! I'd guess the lead prevents you from needing large amounts of gold, which you would in pure or nearly-pure tin.

I don't think it was saturation - though I never looked too far into it.  Rather the diameter diminishes with time as the gold dissolves. So some of the wire has been in longer and is fully dissolved. But some of it went into the solder only 0.5sec before it solidified, and the lower temperature and brief time mean it didn't dissolve.  It's an alternative to trying to control the temperature and time super precisely. If I pulled the wire out before the solder hardened, it usually had a conical/tapered tip.

I did manage to get a bond that seemed mechanically sound using a similar method to @JackB, timing it just right before the solder on the big (30 AWG) copper wire solidified.  This was even in lead-free solder.  I wondered about local saturation in a small part of the solder bead, as I was reinforcing the joint with conductive epoxy

You may want to consider a different kind of wire.  There are many materials that are not likely to dissolve in lead or tin because of their high melting temperatures, such as tungsten and platinum.
